# error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]. I have provided my code below, I am new to coding so feel free to help me out;)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers

[I have provided the screenshot of the code and the error is also visible i don't understand the error and will appreciatle any kind of help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b1qS.png)

Comment: Copy code to post, and don't attach an image of it.

Comment: Your merge expects an int* as it's first parameter while you are sending an int. The order of parameters passed to a function is important.

Comment: The order and number of arguments in the call to `merge(n1, n2, arr1, arr2)` doesn't seem to match the definition of `merge(int *arr1, int n1, int *arr2, int n2, int *ans)` in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a pointer to you array, and then give it to merge function.
Or replace merge(*int *arr1*, int n1, *int *arr2*, int n2, *int *ans*) on links to array

Answer (score 0):

`merge` is declared as `void merge(int*, int, int*, int, int*)`. But in `main` you call it as

```
merge(n1, n2, arr1, arr2);
```

with `int, int, int*, int*` (5th parameter is missing). You need to allocate some memory for the parameter `ans`. Presumably something like

```
auto arrAns = new int[n1 + n2];
```

(don't forget to `delete[]` it at the end!) and pass them in the correct order:

```
merge(arr1, n1, arr2, n2, arrAns);
```

---

Finally some notes:

- Why not `int arrAns[n1 + n2];`? Because [VLAs are not part of the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)
- Whenever possible use standard containers like `std::vector`, instead of manual memory management.